# LZO Compression - How set the destination length?

Tags: delphi, compression, lzo

I'm trying use lzo.dll to compress some file, my code(Delphi) is that:

```
function lzo2a_999_compress(const Source: Pointer; SourceLength: LongWord; Dest: Pointer; var DestLength: LongWord; WorkMem: Pointer): Integer; cdecl; external 'lzo.dll';
...
function LZO_compress(FileInput, FileOutput: String): Integer;
var
   FInput, FOutput: TMemoryStream;
   WorkMem: Pointer;
   Buffer: TBytes;
   OutputLength: LongWord;
begin
   FInput := TMemoryStream.Create;
   FOutput := TMemoryStream.Create;
   FInput.LoadFromFile(FileInput);
   FInput.Position := 0;
   GetMem(WorkMem, 1000000);
   OutputLength := ??!?!?!;
   SetLength(Buffer, OutputLength);
   try
      lzo2a_999_compress(FInput.Memory, FInput.Size, Buffer, OutputLength, WorkMem);
   finally
      FOutput.CopyFrom(Buffer, Length(Buffer));
   end;
   FOutput.SaveToFile(FileOutput);
   FreeMem(WorkMem, 1000000);
   FInput.Free;
   FOutput.Free;
end;
...
```

The problem is: how set the "OutputLength"? I can allocate a huge size to prevent problems but the FOutput will be the same size of the Buffer. How can I save only the compressed data on OutputFile?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Consider using an alternative to an external dll. See e.g. our [SynLz](https://github.com/synopse/mORMot/blob/master/SynLZ.pas) unit, which is faster at compression and gives slightly better ratio, with optimized asm or pascal source in a single unit. And if you want something standard, with high compression ration, consider using [SynLizard](https://github.com/synopse/mORMot/blob/master/SynLizard.pas), which has several mode of operations, and outperforms most of the other algorithms (it is the LZ4 successor) - it needs a dll with Delphi, but can be statically linked to FPC.

Comment: Thanks but the purpose of my tool requires that the file be compressed with the lzo2a algorithm and these alternatives are based on lzo1x algorithm.

Comment: LZO is sooo 1990's! There are statically linked LZO for Delphi in the Internet. Also consider just compile and link the .obj file if you want to get rid of the dll.

Comment: The compressed file will be read by a third party tool and need to be compressed with lzo2a algorithm to works. Unfortunately, I don't have skills enough to compile the dll sources into an .obj file to use in my project. Would you have any link?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can not (and need not) know it before the function call. It is a `var` parameter and will be set by the function at return. You can then use your `OutputLength` variable to know how many bytes to copy from the buffer:

```
OutputLength := 0; // initialize only
...
try
  lzo2a_999_compress(FInput.Memory, FInput.Size, Buffer, OutputLength, WorkMem);
finally
  FOutput.CopyFrom(Buffer, OutputLength);
```

Comment: I was thinking that was a input parameter and in fact is a output parameter.
Now is working. Thank you!